# What triggers RecyclerView's notifyDataSetChanged function? I am experiencing late execution

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple Android app, and RecyclerView has been one of my biggest hurdles in this.

I have populated RecyclerView with cards (representing people), and within each card is a bunch of `EditText`s.

To prevent constant repopulation of the RecyclerView, I store the edited values (on edit) into an array rather than calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on edit.

When calling `onBindViewHolder`, the data is updated from the array.

On clicking a button, I am to update the data one last time using `notifyDataSetChanged` and start another acitivty, sending the latest data of the people.

```
//refesh data and get latest data
    pa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    PersonResponse personResponse = new PersonResponse(pa.getPersonList());
//go to activity, send the Gson string with the data.
    Intent GoToResultActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    GoToResultActivityIntent.putExtra("personListGson", gson.toJson(personResponse));
    startActivity(GoToResultActivityIntent);
```

However, `onBindViewHolder` is only called after `startActivity` is executed, which is not the ideal scenario. I would like it to be called before `startActivity`. Is there a reason that the adapter does not call it until after the function? perhaps due to the list not being "visible"? Is there a way to force `onBindViewHolder` ?

Many thanks for reading, hope any answers help others understand RecyclerView better. And also hope that there is no other question like this because I've been searching for a while with no solution.

Comment: Look up notifyItemChanged(int pos). It might help you with changing individual items.

Comment: @Ivan86 Thanks for your input. I have tried this as well with no luck. onBindViewHolder is only triggered after startActivity. Side note: From the docs I read that notifyDataSetChanged  is supposed to be a more 'urgent' command in the sense that it reports that both content and structure of the RecyclerView is disrupted.